# How are old satellites removed from orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, reentry

Once the satellite is nonfunctional how are they removed from orbit?

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25751/the-orbital-mass-accelerator-theory/25755#25755

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "properly" configured satellite is one that was engineered, constructed and launched with sufficient fuel and engines to allow the satellite to be placed into a controlled lower orbit with a known expected point of re-entry.

Once the satellite is low enough to experience increased drag due to atmosphere, it will begin to burn up and/or fall into an ocean.

Not all satellites qualify for the above circumstances. [Skylab](http://www.history.com/news/the-day-skylab-crashed-to-earth-facts-about-the-first-u-s-space-stations-re-entry) is one of the more famous examples of "what comes up, must come down" but not necessarily under control.

From the above linked web site:

> Even though Skylab was devised for just a nine-year lifespan, NASA
>   failed to build in any control or navigation mechanisms to return the
>   orbiter to terra firma.

Comment: Looks like China's space station is going to do something similar now as well. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

@fred_dot_u's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25862/12102) is only partially true:

It's not reasonably expected for a satellite to be able to deorbit itself since the delta v cost can be very high for GEO orbits (1500m/s).

While LEO satellites are expected to deorbit themselves, generally over the pacific, GEO satellites cannot do this and then are moved into a higher, [grave yard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graveyard_orbit) orbit.

However, not all satellites are able to do this since failures can (and do) happen before the end of life of the satellite.

Comment: Should I ask if what are done with those satellite?

Comment: @Muze Nothing. They become space junk.