# Can bad satellites be pulled out of orbit with an Orbital Mass Accelerator?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, orbital-maneuver, engines, magnetic-field

Could an [Orbital Mass Accelerator OMA](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25751/the-orbital-mass-accelerator-engine-theory) be used to knock other satellites out of orbit? Leaping from satellite to satellite using a magnetic field to accelerate some useless satellites and decelerate others can the OMA maneuver only using a magnetic field on other satellites?

Each satellite schematics could be uploaded to adjust the magnetic field to each satellite before interception. In theory a coarse could be plotted out eliminating all the debris from orbit.
Why? To prevent the Kepler syndrome from happening.

---

or maybe something as simple as as capture, bag and magnetically spring off the pile of satellites pushing them it out of orbit?
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a question and answer site, and your question was about if this idea would work.  Please don't edit responses to the answers into your question to try to answer that question--if your answer is "yes, my idea works" you can add it as an answer yourself.

Comment: Now that this has been edited some more, it seems like you would really be better-served by a discussion forum.  Stackexchange is not suited for back-and-forth, and you're obviously making this up as you go along.

Comment: No, you've literally added a question about a completely different capture-and-hold-then-eject system.  Asking about a particular solution to Kessler Syndrome is acceptable for this site; brainstorming multiple solutions in a single question is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first question: it's theoretically possible to use a big coil gun/OMA to change the momentum of a satellite.  Change it enough and its periapsis could end up too low for orbit to be sustained.  Sure.

On the leaping from satellite to satellite:  I don't think it's a good idea.

- Satellites and other aerospace structures tend to be heavily composed of aluminum and titanium, with fiber materials rising in popularity.  You may need to know a lot about the composition to properly tune the magnetic field of your OMA in advance.
- Each encounter provides a single impulse, which means that impulse has to be precisely planned to make the next rendezvous.  It's not impossible, but [Russell Borogove's answer to your previous question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25755/11262) still applies.  There are perturbations affecting both the OMA and its targets.  To make that more difficult, you need to be near the nodes of both targets' orbits to make a single impulse transfer between them.
- Not only do you have to manage to encounter your target satellites, but you have to encounter them such that the momentum transfer from the transfer gets you to the next satellite.  That means you need a certain velocity at the encounter point (possibly with some margin from doing some kind of hand-waving modification of your magnetic field).  These rendezvous can be planned, but again, you're asking for a lot of precision from a single impulse.
- Your encounter time is very short for a target moving retrograde to your OMA, making your required precision even dearer for those.  But if you only (or primarily) intercept posigrade targets I think you'll find that you're inevitably lifting the OMA, which may eventually strand it out of reach of its targets.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, yes.

In practice, no:

- There is too much orbital perturbations to aim from far away without corrections
- The energy requirements are insane
- The forces exerted on the crafts would be humongous

Comment: @Muze please share the assumptions you're making to come up with that "1 second" (of what?  encounter time?  Solar power collection?) by editing them into the question so that we can improve our answers.  Right now there isn't nearly enough information to back up numbers.

Comment: @Muze being "solar powered" doesn't change anything: you need vast amount of electricity, which mean huge solar panels, which mean huge mass, which means less acceleration, which mean you need more propellant (dead satellites).