# How to convert data from GLONASS almanac (*.AGL) to the two-line element set? (*.TLE)?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, orbital-elements

For example, I have the GLONASS AGL:

```
01 02 2019   12606
 7   5  1  31 01 2019  0.268941250E+05  0.000000000E+00  0.000000000E+00  0.534057617E-04
-0.1830244E+00  0.8393288E-02 -0.6981506E+00  0.1260757E-02 -0.2655885E+04  0.6103516E-04
```

How to get TLE format like this:

```
COSMOS 2477 (745)       
1 37868U 11064B   19031.65557970 -.00000008  00000-0  00000+0 0  9990
2 37868  64.5058 164.2131 0014781 237.3537 122.5067  2.13101723 56375
```

I have a descripton of both formats, but they are very different and I have no idea, for example, how to get mean motion from AGL, or some other parameters...

Comment: Because of the way TLEs are generated and used, that might be really difficult, and when you are done still not really accurate. The values in TLE's are not true orbital elements and they only work when propagated with SGP4 or similar. There may be a much better way to do whatever you'd like to de. It might be a good idea for you to describe your goal in a little more detail. See [Do not make FAKE TLEs!](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26124/12102) and [How to correctly make a fake, counter-propagating TLE?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32725/12102)

Comment: Instead, maybe just look up the TLEs for your satellites? Click `Glonass Operational` here: https://www.celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/

Comment: Unfortunately in my case I only have GLONASS data and I can't get the TLE from NORAD. I want to convert data from GLONASS almanac to TLE and then SGP4 will propagate it

Comment: okay I don't understand exactly, my link goes to Celestrak which is an open web site used by people around the planet. The data is from NORAD but it's not a NORAD site. okay good luck.