# How would propagation differ between a GEO and a Retrograde GEO?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, geosynchronous, altitude, mapping, retrograde-orbit

A Binary Equatorial Synchronous Retrograde Orbit is an orbit that would travel in the opposite direction of GEO and would pass over the same point on Earth twice per day at the same altitude of GEO. How would propagation or the shape of the orbit differ from regular GEO?

Would the satellite in this retrograde orbit be at the same altitude over the same point on Earth on each orbit?

What would be the proper name for this type of retrograde orbit?

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-orbit-of-a-natural-satellite

Comment: This is an interesting question, and different than [How much does the tidal effect affect satellites in a retrograde orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32817/12102)